# Ajax in Rails 4 not update the content

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have the controller: "Likes" with action: "create"

```
def create
 @micropost = Micropost.find(params[:micropost_id])
 current_user.like(@micropost)
 @micropost.reload

 @likes = @micropost.count_likes

 respond_to do |format|
   format.html { redirect_to root_path }
   format.js
 end
end
```

This action will request json and update the view using ajax, the view will render correctly if I write:

```
$("#like_count-<%= @micropost.id %>").html('<%= @likes %>');
```

But writing:

```
$("#like_count-<%= @micropost.id %>").html('<%= @micropost.count_likes %>');
```

causes no effect. I also have checked that after @micropost.reload, the value of @micropost.count_likes has been updated. I don't know the reason why this happen. Hope you guys could help. Here is the source code of Micropost:

```
class Micropost < ActiveRecord::Base
 # micropost belong to one user
 belongs_to :user

 # many user can like one micropost
 has_many :user_likes, class_name: "Like",
       foreign_key: "micropost_id",
       dependent: :destroy
 has_many :likers, through: :user_likes, source: :user

 default_scope -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
 mount_uploader :picture, PictureUploader

 validates(:content, presence: true, length: {:maximum => 200})
 validates(:user_id, presence: true)
 validate :picture_size

 def count_likes
   user_likes.length > 0 ? "(#{user_likes.length})" : ""
 end

 private
 # Validates the size of an uploaded picture.
 def picture_size
   if picture.size > 1.megabytes
     errors.add(:picture, "should be less than 1MB")
  end
 end
end
```

**Update**

The form post request to Likes#create:

```
<%= form_for(micropost.user_likes.build, remote: true) do |f| %>
<div><%= hidden_field_tag :micropost_id, micropost.id %></div>
<%= f.submit "like", class: "btn btn-primary", style: "width: 100px" %>
<% end %>
```

The User class:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
...
# user can like many microposts
has_many :pos_likes, class_name: "Like",
       foreign_key: "user_id",
       dependent: :destroy
has_many :fav_posts, through: :pos_likes, source: :micropost
...
# like a post
def like(micropost)
   self.pos_likes.create(user_id: self.id, micropost_id: micropost.id)
end
```

Comment: Are you sure the reason is in the AJAX?
Could you add params sent to the controller as well?

Comment: And also add the `User#like` code

Comment: @NickolayKondratenko I have updated the question

Comment: Check what does `current_user.like(@micropost)` return

Comment: @NickolayKondratenko The function  `current_user.like(@micropost)` in action `create` return a new "Like"

Comment: Ok but I'm not sure if it saves it. Try please `current_user.like(@micropost).new_record?`

Also there is a good explanation about the difference between `#count` and `#length` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11905364/difference-between-size-length-and-count-in-complicated-activerecord-case
So try to replace `user_likes.length` with `user_likes.count`

Comment: thank you @NickolayKondratenko, using `count` solve my problem. Good explanation from the link. Could you give the answer for this post so I could mark you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is in using `#length` instead of `#count` method.
Below there is a good explanation of the difference between them:

[Difference between size, length and count in complicated ActiveRecord case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11905364/difference-between-size-length-and-count-in-complicated-activerecord-case)

So to fix it you need to use `user_likes.count` instead of `user_likes.length` at your `Micropost#count_likes`